# Embedded Systems project Google maps with GSM

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, gsm

In my project, gsm module gives the location of the system. I'm sending that location to a mobile number. Now what I want is that when the location is received on the mobile, it's shown in google maps. How can I do this?

Comment: So basically in my project, gsm module gives the location of the system. I'm sending that location to a mobile number. Now what I want is that when the location is received on the mobile, it's shown in google maps. How should i go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps has an API you can drive, low volume use is free, google for it! Also consider OpenStreetMap.org, any level of use is free.